# Sharing data in Next.JS 13 Server Components

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next.js13, app-router

As we cannot use context in Server Components of Next.JS 13 when we use App Router, What is the best way to share data between different server components?

I have some a root `layout.tsx` and some other nested `layout.tsx` and `page.tsx`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data. If You `fetch` the data and use it in different RSC, just fetch it again. Next.js `fetch` provides caching.

If your data is expensive to compute, or it is not fetched (e.g., comes from the local file system, third party) use React `cache`.

```
import { cache } from 'react';

export const getExpensiveData = cache(function getExpensiveData(): ExpensiveData {
// Retrieve data and do expensive processing
  return expensiveData;
})
```

For simple cases, if possible, pass props down to nested components.

Usually, you start fetching/computing data in the page component. This works just fine.

There is still one thing missing, at least to me. What if you pass props to a Server Component and want to reuse the props in nested Server Components but can't pass props down? I have no simple solution, but all use cases I meet could be easily solved by using the data in client components (context) only.

Does this help?